# strpslit a character array and convert to dataframe simultaneously

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have what feels like a difficult data manipulation problem, and am hoping to get some guidance. Here is a test version of what my current array looks like, as well as what dataframe I hope to obtain:

```
dput(test)
c("<play quarter=\"1\" oncourt-id=\"\" time-minutes=\"12\" time-seconds=\"0\" id=\"1\"/>", "<play quarter=\"2\" oncourt-id=\"\" time-minutes=\"10\" id=\"1\"/>")

test 
[1] "<play quarter=\"1\" oncourt-id=\"\" time-minutes=\"12\" time-seconds=\"0\" id=\"1\"/>"
[2] "<play quarter=\"2\" oncourt-id=\"\" time-minutes=\"10\" id=\"1\"/>" 

desired_df
  quarter    oncourt-id    time-minutes    time-seconds    id
1       1            NA              12               0     1
2       3            NA              10              NA     1
```

There are a few problems I am dealing with:

1. the character array "test" has backslashes where there should be nothing, but i was having difficulty using gsub in this format gsub("\", "", test).
2. not every element in test has the same number of entries, note in the example that the 2nd element doesn't have time-seconds, and so for the dataframe I would prefer it to return NA.

I have tried using strsplit(test, " ") to first split on spaces, which only exist between different column entires, but then I am returned with a list of lists that is just as difficult to deal with.

Comment: This looks like `XML`? Why not consider parsing it with the `XML` library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got xml there.  You could parse it, then run `rbindlist` on the result.  This will probably be a lot less hassle than trying to split the name-value pairs as strings.

```
dflist <- lapply(test, function(x) {
    df <- as.data.frame.list(XML::xmlToList(x))
    is.na(df) <- df == ""
    df
})

data.table::rbindlist(dflist, fill = TRUE)
#    quarter oncourt.id time.minutes time.seconds id
# 1:       1         NA           12            0  1
# 2:       2         NA           10           NA  1
```

Note: You will need the *XML* and *data.table* packages for this solution.